# Turn an if statement into a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 charts which I need to redraw.

This is the code I have to do one:

```
var arrOfChartContainers = ["TopLeft","TopRight","BottomLeft"];


var myAutoRefresh = setInterval(function(){
    if($("#TopLeft_chartConfig").css("display")==="none"){
        drawChart("TopLeft");
    }else{
        clearInterval(myAutoRefresh);
    }
},3000);
```

I don't want to do copy this 2 more times and redraw my two other charts. How can I loop through my charts if I want to do all three at the same time on an internval?

Comment: use .each() function on the array?

Comment: Have you tried a loop then? What was your problem? Should the interval stop when all three are drawn then?

Comment: Sorry, my problem is that I don't know how to do it. I'm very new to coding. The interval should keep going, I need all the charts to continuously refresh to give the impression of real-time updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/):

```
$.each(arrOfChartContainers, function(index, entry) {
    $("#" + entry + "_chartConfig").doSomethingWithItHere();
});
```

E.g.:

```
$.each(arrOfChartContainers, function(index, entry) {
    var $chart = $("#" + entry + "_chartConfig");
    if ($chart.css("display") === "none") {
        drawChart(entry);
    }
});
```

Probably worth changing `drawChart` to accept the jQuery object directly rather than using the name indirectly.

Comment: "Probably worth changing drawChart to accept the jQuery object directly" I'm not sure I know what you mean.

Comment: @Batman: Well, in your original code, you're passing the string "TopLeft" into `drawChart`. I have no idea what your `drawChart` does with that string, but in your other code that string is *part* of an `id` value you're using to look up an element and get a jQuery object for it. So I figured it might make more sense to pass that object into `drawChart`. Or not, of course, depending on what it does.

Comment: Well if we're looping and I guess "entry" is the jQuery object, there's no way for us to pass the string in drawChart, if we pass the string it would always redraw the chart but 3 times. This is what it does https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/drawing_charts#drawchart

Comment: @Batman: **All** of the code above goes inside your `setInterval` call; it loops through the three strings in your array, one by one. And no, `entry` isn't the jQuery object, it's a string. I recommend taking a step back from your current task and working through a few tutorials.

Comment: I don't think I follow. For example in Javascript in a for loop we'd have something like array[i] and I could pass that through to drawChart(array[i])... is 'entry' serving the same purpose here? And yea JQuery is definitely in my list of things I need to take a deeper look at.

Comment: @Batman: Yes. See the linked documentation for how `$.each` works.

Answer (score 1):

HTML: Add a class to your chart elements to accommodate the below js.

JS:

```
$('.someuniversalchartclass').each(function(){
   ($(this).hasClass('ninja')) ? drawChart($(this)) : clearInterval(myAutoRefresh);
});
```

CSS:

```
.ninja {
   display:none;
}
```

Comment: You should probably explain in details, like saying that "someuniversalchartclass" need to be added to every chart object, etc... Anyway, "ninja" is a good idea for a "display: none" class :)

Comment: True.  Edit in progress.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use for loop. Also instead of checking css you could use `.is(':visible')`

```
for (var i = 0; i < arrOfChartContainers.length; i++) {
    if ($('#' + arrOfChartContainers[i] + '_chartConfig').is(':visible')) {
        drawChart(arrOfChartContainers[i]);
    }
}
```